# html page for language chooser

Tags: html, css

I want to have html page where I show the user different languages to choose from. Can any body help with html code applicable for this? the attached image is just a sample of what I want. It contains 3 language along with options along with 3 flags and I want the user to click on the flag or the language name.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code so far.

Comment: I don't have a code because I need someone to guide to write one

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).